# Second order ODE bessel function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, heat-equation, legendre-polynomials

I'm currently trying to find the solutions to this second order ODE:

R'' + R'/r + c*R = 0, where R(r) and c is an arbitary constant.

I found this page https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/heat-equation-on-ball-one-dimensional-description where they had already solved this equation. I'm pretty sure he had his dr should've been d/dr but whatever. I am currently at a complete loss as to how he got to that equation.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dR}{dr}+cR=0 \tag{1}$$
Case $c>0$ :

Change of variable $x=\sqrt{c}\:r \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2R}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dR}{dx}+R=0$

This is the standard Bessel differential equation which general solution is :
$$R(x)=c_1J_0(x)+c_2Y_0(x)$$
Thus the solution of equation (1) is :
$$R(r)=c_1J_0(\sqrt{c}\:r)+c_2Y_0(\sqrt{c}\:r) $$
Bessel functions of first and second kind.

Case $c=0$ :
$$R(r)=c_1\ln|r|+c_2$$

Case $c<0$ :

Do the same with change of variable $x=\sqrt{-c}\:r$ which leads to
$$R(r)=c_1I_0(\sqrt{-c}\:r)+c_2K_0(\sqrt{-c}\:r) $$
Modified Bessel functions of first and second kind.